# Create new instances of a class from an array of classes with Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, instance

I'm trying to create an array of classes in Java. Not objects, but classes. Currently I have a class MyBaseClass and I extend three classes MyClass1, MyClass2, and MyClass3 from it. I store these classes to a static array like this:

```
private static MyBaseClass[] classes = {
        new MyClass1(),
        new MyClass2(),
        new MyClass3()
};

public static MyBaseClass getInstanceOfClass(int index) {
    return classes[index];
}
```

and then I use those methods like this:

```
try {
    MyBaseClass obj = getInstanceOfClass(index).getClass().newInstance();
} catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now I'm wondering if I could do this in an easier way. If I could create an array of classes I might be able to escape the getInstanceOfClass() method and some possible exceptions. I tried doing this:

```
private static Class<MyBaseClass>[] classes = {
        MyClass1.class,
        MyClass2.class,
        MyClass3.class
};
```

But this gives me an error "Incompatible types" as MyClass1 is not equal to MyBaseClass. Interestingly enough, this seemingly works:

```
private static Class<?>[] classes = {
        new MyClass1().getClass(),
        new MyClass2().getClass(),
        new MyClass3().getClass()
};
```

But the idea of that is horrible and it's even marked by my debugger. So, any better ways of doing this?

**Edit:**

This works:

```
private static Class<?>[] classes = {
        MyClass1.class,
        MyClass2.class,
        MyClass3.class
};
```

But then the result of `getInstanceOfClass(index).newInstance();` is an Object so I have to do typecasting. I'm not really sure if that's safe in this case...

Comment: I dont think you can create arrays of generic type,due to type erasure

Comment: The most unnerving thing in this is that at least Android Studio doesn't mark `Class<?>[]` or `Class<MyBaseClass>[]` with an error. But `Class<? extends MyBaseClass>[]` is marked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to indicated that you are looking for possibly subclasses of `MyBaseClass`. For this you can add `? extends` to the generic type description. Note that this will also accept `MyBaseClass` itself.

Added to this, you can use `.class` to get the `Class` object of a class, instead of making an isntance and calling `getClass()`.

Unfortunately this doesn't work with arrays because they don't allow generic types. So you have to add them to a list (which is almost always a good thing):

```
private static ArrayList<Class<? extends MyBaseClass>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<? extends MyBaseClass>>();

...

classes.add(MyClass1.class),
classes.add(MyClass2.class),
classes.add(MyClass3.class),
```

Comment: This gets marked as an error "Generic array creation".

Comment: Ah you are right, arrays don't allow subclasses, you can store them in a List.

Comment: I don't have a List. The code you posted above gets marked with an error. Funny enough that `Class<?>[]` or `Class<MyBaseClass>[]` doesn't get marked but `Class<? extends MyBaseClass>[]`gets.

Comment: [You cannot create arrays of parameterized types.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays)

Comment: From java 7 ,you can use diamond operator too

Comment: Yeah, generics make it really complicated, as said in Java 7 you don't need to repeat it after the new. In a future version they will support static initialization of objects.

Comment: Static initialization in the future? But I can initialize that object in a `static { ... }` block can I? At least it seems to work. And thanks for the diamond operator hint.

Comment: Yes you certainly can, if you want an immutable list you can also do `Arrays.asList()`.